# How to sort String List by newest in dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart, sorting

i have `String List`, per element contains **userId+DateTime**

```
    List<String> = [
   '9DWXpF6V4vN8oxqvsHKnOBg2Rz2022-09-14 00:07:52.707',
   '8jk9wQ0U5gNyekzNz84SDb0jDTf12022-09-12 00:07:52.704',
   '0RMRZFCifmSe2CGW6k7Rvq8gvni2022-09-13 00:07:52.704'
    ]
```

now i need to sort the list from newest to oldest depends of that `DateTime` next to `User Id`

so i am trying the output look like following

```
  List<String> = [
   '9DWXpF6V4vN8oxqvsHKnOBg2Rz2022-09-14 00:07:52.707',
   '0RMRZFCifmSe2CGW6k7Rvq8gvni2022-09-13 00:07:52.704'
   '8jk9wQ0U5gNyekzNz84SDb0jDTf12022-09-12 00:07:52.704',
        ]
```

Note : in my example i did care in day date just to explain my use case but i need to sort my list According to the most recent date and **time**, not only day date

How can i implement this ?

**Edit**
i have added two fixed words 'START' and 'END' between each `DateTime` element so i can filter it using `RegExp` like following

```
List<String> = [
   '9DWXpF6V4vN8oxqvsHKnOBg2RzSTART2022-09-14 00:07:52.707END',
   '8jk9wQ0U5gNyekzNz84SDb0jDTf1START2022-09-12 00:07:52.704END',
   '0RMRZFCifmSe2CGW6k7Rvq8gvniSTART2022-09-13 00:07:52.704END'
    ] 

list.sort((a,b) => a[DateTime.parse(RegExp(r'|START(.*)END'))]
.compareTo(b[DateTime.parse(RegExp(START(.*)END'))]));
```

print(list); // it does not work

Comment: You need to break the strings into a User Id part and a DateTime object, then sort the datapairs based on the DateTime objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Now with START and END, this should work:

```
RegExp regex = RegExp(r'START(.*)END$');
list.sort(
  (first, second) {
    String? firstDateString = regex.firstMatch(first)?.group(1);
    if (firstDateString == null) {
      throw ArgumentError("$first does not contain any date");
    }
    String? secondDateString = regex.firstMatch(second)?.group(1);
    if (secondDateString == null) {
      throw ArgumentError("$second does not contain any date");
    }
    DateTime firstDate = DateTime.parse(firstDateString);
    DateTime secondDate = DateTime.parse(secondDateString);
    return secondDate.compareTo(firstDate);
  }
);
```

UPDATE:

In order to use `=>` we have to convert everything inside the outer curly brackets into one statement. There are two ways:

1. We extract this into a new method which actually does the comparison of two strings. This can look like this:

```
int compareDateString(String first, String second) {
  String? firstDateString = regex.firstMatch(first)?.group(1);
  if (firstDateString == null) {
    throw ArgumentError("$first does not contain any date");
  }
  String? secondDateString = regex.firstMatch(second)?.group(1);
  if (secondDateString == null) {
    throw ArgumentError("$second does not contain any date");
  }
  DateTime firstDate = DateTime.parse(firstDateString);
  DateTime secondDate = DateTime.parse(secondDateString);
  return secondDate.compareTo(firstDate);
}

list.sort((first, second) => compareDateString(first, second));
// or shorter:
list.sort(compareDateString);
```

2. Or we can stop throwing ArgumentErrors and shrink everything into one statement. I do not recommend this as you always should throw an error if the arguments do not contain a date. This will look like this:

```
list.sort((first, second) => DateTime.parse(regex.firstMatch(second)!.group(1)!).compareTo(DateTime.parse(regex.firstMatch(first)!.group(1)!)));
```

This one-liner expects both strings to have dates. If not you get "Null check operator used on null value". How I already mentioned, I recommend to use (1).

Comment: it always gives errors

Comment: The ArgumentError which is thrown inside the method? Or any other errors? In either case please show me the error message.

Comment: it always thrown errors which is inside the method Yes

Comment: Please show the error message

Comment: throw ArgumentError("$secondDateString does not contain any date");

Comment: throw ArgumentError("$firstDateString does not contain any date");

Comment: I mean the error which is shown in the terminal because $firstDateString should be evaluated to the string which does not contain any date. I need the string to have a look how its formatted

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): null does not contain any date

Comment: That means that you have `null` values inside your list. You need to filter that out or do something else with it.

Comment: i have no null value inside my list .. plase make sure of your  RegExp

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, try it now. It should show which string has no date. You should also let me know how these dates are formatted.

Comment: it is the same .. i edited my question can you please take a look

Comment: I edited my answer. With START and END this should work.

Comment: thank you TripleNine . it is work fine but can you please tell me how could i use => instead of return ? .. if you could edit your answer to use => instead of return i would be most thankful to you

Comment: I edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: thank you so mush it is so useful and i would like to use  list.sort((first, second) => DateTime.parse(regex.firstMatch(second)!.group(1)!).compareTo(DateTime.parse(regex.firstMatch(first)!.group(1)!)));

because in my case  my list will never contains null value

Comment: your answer really saved my time ,, thanks bro